# CLLocationManager: Unexpectedly Found Nil While Unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Here's my code in ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import TwitterKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

    var manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //calling CLLocation
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //map region
        let locationZoom = self.manager.location
        var latitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.longitude
        var centerLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
        var centerLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = locationZoom.coordinate.longitude
        var latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.03
        var longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.03
        var span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
        var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(centerLatitude, centerLongitude)
        var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span) // this creates a map region with the center
        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func zoom(sender: AnyObject) {


        let locationZoom = self.manager.location

        var latitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.longitude
        var centerLatitude:CLLocationDegrees = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
        var centerLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = locationZoom.coordinate.longitude
        var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.03
        var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.03
        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
        var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(centerLatitude, centerLongitude)
        var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span) // this creates a map region with the center
        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now, the error is described as thus:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Thread 1 is pointing towards this being the issue:

```
var latitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
```

However, when testing this on the simulator, I have also found the issue to occur with the longitude variable. Still, I do not understand why the values for both longitude and latitude are set to "nil." I have set up CLLocationManager correctly, made sure to modify info.plist as necessary to include `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, etc. What's going on, and how do I correct this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when your view loads it has not received any location update. Implement  DidUpdateLocations and access location info there. if you need reference you can look [DidUpdateLocations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:)

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let locationZoom = locations.last as! CLLocation
    let latitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude: Double = locationZoom.coordinate.longitude
    println(latitude)
    println(longitude)
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the application to stop crashing (with a solution very similar to yours, although yours is much cleaner, so I used that instead), but now, the application defaults the latitude/longitude coordinates to (0, 0). 

I'm pretty sure the issue is due to the fact that on both the simulator and my iPhone, there is never a call for requesting permission to use location, even though I have manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization().

Comment: Can you show how and where are you declaring your lat / lon vars?

Comment: I edited my original post to showcase where I declare the latitude/longitude variables.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I fixed the problem altogether. It appears to have been an indentation issue and wrapping the "manager" code in the viewDidLoad() when it shouldn't have been.